# Changing CSS of a table cell based on the value in another cell of same row in HTML

Tags: html, css, sql-server, knockout.js, sql-server-2012

I am working on an HTML web page where I have a table with some data in it and I am trying to control CSS for an entire column in the table based on the values in another column and same row

For example, In the following screenshot I have my data

[image]

In the above picture, I have `Volume, Price and Type`. Now, I want to control the color of `Price column` based on the corresponding value in `Type` Column. Like for `Price=10` I have `Type` as `Sell`, so I want to make the value `10` to `red color` and similarly if type is Buy then Price value should be in Yellow.

I am trying to do that using following script

```
<td data-bind="text: Volume"></td>    
                <td data-bind="text: (typeof Price() === 'number') ? Price().toFixed(2) : '',css:{cclientType:Type=='Sell'}"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Type"></td>
```

But, that doesn't seem to be working.

Provided, the data is coming from a `Knockout View model` which in turn is pulling from `SQL Server`.

**Is there a better way I could achieve this?**

Comment: if `Type` is an observable, use `css:{cclientType:Type()=='Sell'}`

Comment: Worked fine and how do I give it multiple CSS as I mentioned in the question that if it sell then red and if it is buy then Yellow?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a ko.computed function to each of your data items to help you determine the css:

```
  self.volume = ko.observable(volume);
  self.price = ko.observable(price);
  self.type = ko.observable(type);
  self.priceCss = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.type() == 'buy') {
        return 'buy-class';
    } else if (self.type() == 'sell') {
        return 'sell-class';
    } else return '';
});
```

This can then be added to your markup:

```
<tr>
  <td data-bind="text:volume"></td>
  <td data-bind="text:price, css: priceCss"></td>
  <td data-bind="text:type"></td>
</tr>
```

A plunker demonstrating this can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/joXExWu8QxOc5J4JU0Ke?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Dev.
Please, try this! Works.

```
 <td data-bind="text: volume"></td>    
 <td data-bind="text: (typeof price() === 'number') ? price().toFixed(2) : '',css:{ cclientType: type() == 'sell'}"></td>
 <td data-bind="text: type"></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would set styles on the `<tr>` based on the contents of type column (or any other column) and handle everything you need in CSS.

Eg.

```
<tr class="sell">
    <td>100</td>    
    <td>10.00</td>    
    <td>Sell</td>    
</tr>

tr.sell td:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

If you don't like using the `nth-of-type` selector, you can set a class on the `<td>` and then your CSS selector would be:

```
tr.sell td.price {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Well, That makes entire column red no matter what the value in Type Column

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/crq4jrfo/ Try changing the value in last column to Buy or Sell, No matter what you input the value, it just gives the price column a red color

Comment: @Dev: Of course it won't. It's not magic.  You need to add logic in your view or KO to set the tr class for each row based on the price of each row.